# Powershell -- changing Network Adapter's Name/Description

Tags: windows, powershell, networking, perfmon

I've been working with many VMs and doing some monitoring stuff. 
My current problem is that the Network Adapter/Interface name in Perfmon seems to vary across operating system. It can be anything from Microsoft Hyper-V Network Adapter to Microsoft Network Adapter #3.

I've been looking into registry editing stuff, but it doesn't seem to be easy since they are stored in ridiculously ugly GUID sets.

I've also considered using the win32_networkadapter class under wmi-objects, but I seem to be only able to get, not set, the interfacedescription property (which I'm not even sure would affect Perfmon's counter name).

Any guidance would be very much appreciated!

Comment: What issue are you trying to solve? Are you wanting to physically change the network adapter name on all the computers? i.e. -Set- the the name (NOT recommended - there should be a good reason to do this). Or are you concerned that the name of the Network adapters in Perfmon are different from computer to computer which makes reporting inconvenient? The simple answer to the second question is, no, you can't change the name that is displayed by Perfmon because it is just plain returning the values from the adapters.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm doing more of the second option, I am trying to change the interface name of the network adapters -- while I can't change them that way, is there any way I could get a way to modify the registry keys/values consistently? My goal is trying to get all the network adapter names consistent across the VMs -- the way the monitoring system is set up pretty much requires this, unfortunately.

Comment: Unfortunately, changing the registry keys/values is basically the same as physically changing the names. Most monitoring systems usually can handle different network names. what system are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using server 2012 or windows 8.1's Hyper-V there are a few commands that could do this.

Get-Vmnetworkadapter and set-vmnetworkadapter